# Joomla 2.5 latest article from a category link

Tags: php, joomla2.5, article

I would like to create a menu item with dynamic links to the latest article published in a given category.

I don't want to use the default category blog link because I want the link to leed straight to the article page and avoid duplicate content.

hope this is comprehensible, thx for helping me with this issue.

Comment: Have you find a solution for this? I'm really interested in this too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to accomplish this, one with code, one without.

The no code method involves replacing the standard Joomla com_content with a CCK extension that has a latest item functionality built in - I know K2 has it for sure, there are likely others.

The other method would require you to create a new model/view/menu item that only pulls the latest published article. This would actually not be terribly difficult since you could basically copy most of the category model and use most of the article view to come up with what you need. The changes are a little too involved to post here however.

Comment: thx for this answer, I'll try the code solution although my php skills aren't the best, I think it is a pity to install K2 only for this feature. I'll have a look if I find a lighter module or component.

Comment: You might want to download K2 just to look at the code they use for their latest item menu item. It should be very similar and should help if you are not very familiar with PHP.